# Testing static framework via development pod feature in Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, opencv, cocoapods

I have a framework written in Swift. I distribute it via Cocoapods as a static binary framework. I also have an app using the framework and I develop the framework as a **development pod**.

Recently I had to add OpenCV as a dependency to the framework and an Objective-C  Wrapper class for an ability to work with OpenCV from Swift code. Due to **"static transitioning dependencies" error** on `pod install` step I had to add `spec.static_framework = true` line to my podspec. The error is gone but I have another one – more than 100 errors on Swift syntax.

If compile the framework to binary and install from another repository as a usual pod, not development – everything is okay. But I need to make changes and test them in real-time, not compile and uploading binary every minute.

Any advice on how to test **static framework** via **development pod** feature is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not the best solution (also it doesn't use development pod), but at least it worked for me when I had to debug my Framework and my App together (it was a similar situation because normally the App uses the Framework as cocoapod), edit Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!

workspace 'App.xcworkspace'

target 'App' do
  project 'App.xcodeproj'

  # 1 - comment out the normal dependency
  # pod 'MyFramework', '1.9'
end

# 2 - this section is added
target 'MyFramework'
  project '/Users/me/path/to/MyFramework.xcodeproj'
  pod 'DependencyOfMyFramework'
end
```

Then **ensure** you don't have uncommitted changes in App.xcodeproj.

Close Xcode, run `pod install`, open xcworkspace again, **manually** add `MyFramework` and `DependencyOfMyFramework` as dependencies to the App (Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content), maybe add some Framework Search Paths in case of errors.

Worked for me, but I realize it can be pretty inconvenient if you do this regularly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try.

Comment: Wow, it worked. But it seems it's not necessary to manually add `MyFramework` every time I change something. As framework' xcproject is embedded in an app workspace, it somehow provides an actual version of compiled framework embedded in the app.